# How do we drop partitions in hive with regex. Is it possible?

Tags: regex, hive, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I am trying to run the following

```
alter table historical_data drop partition (my_date not rlike '[A-Za-z]');
```

Which gives me an Exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 2:69 mismatched input 'not' expecting set null in drop partition statement
```

I couldn't find anything similar. I did see one answer on some question in SO but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp is not supported unfortunately.

You can use all these comparators `< > <= >= <> = !=` maybe it will help. See usage in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56646879/2700344

See also this jira [Extend ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION syntax to use all comparators](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2908)

Also one more jira not implemented yet: [Extend ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION syntax to use multiple conditions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11337)

[Impala supports LIKE](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/impala_alter_table.html) in drop partition:

```
alter table historical_data drop partition (year < 1995, last_name like 'A%');
```

Created this [Jira for adding regexp](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21652), please vote in the Jira if you need it.

Comment: Yeah , we can use < or > , and if it is a date like pattern similar to my case , we can use a future date (my_date > '2020-12-12') . But it could be a new request to add regex similar to the Jiras request for other features you shared , and this would yet be unresolved and closed. Thank you leftjoin.